# Do tensor norms exist?

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, tensors, multilinear-algebra

Does there exist norms for tensors, as an extension for the ordinary matrix norm?

For example, if there is a derivative of a matrix [A] with respect to a vector {x}, does the norm of this derivative exist? If it does, how do we calculate it?

Comment: Do you mean rank 3 tensors here? If so, sure, pick a norm on the space of rank 2 tensors (i.e. matrices) and take the induced norm on the rank 3 tensors.

Comment: @Ian Yes I'm referring to rank 3 tensors. Would you mind explain it a bit more, please? I'm not familiar with tensors.

Comment: A rank 3 tensor is a linear map on a space of rank 2 tensors. But rank 2 tensors, say from $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, can be identified with rank 1 tensors in the obvious way (concatenate the columns into one big column vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$). So you can define an operator norm on a space of rank 3 tensors just like you do with rank 2 tensors. You can also choose a norm which isn't even induced if you want, just as you can with rank 2 tensors.